# C# : force a query to use specific index

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-express

Using C# & a SQL Server Express database

I have a table that has 4 columns `File`, `Herd`, `Dir`, `DateTime`. Primary key is `File`.

I've created an index on (`Herd asc, Dir desc, DateTime desc`).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX[IX_HerdHist_tb_Herd]
N[HerdHist_tb] ([hh_HerdNumber] ASC, [hh_Dir] DESC,hh_DateTime] DESC);
```

When I query the table I want to see the results by the index NOT by the primary key, which is what is happening.

If the table contains the following:

```
File                  Herd     Dir      DateTime
------------------------------------------------------------
20160209\05010000.123 05010000 20160209 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
20160210\05010000.123 05010000 20160210 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
20160210\05010000.124 05010000 20160210 10:10:10 06:06:06pm
20160210\04011111.123 04011111 20160210 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
```

I select a Herd and get.

```
20160209\05010000.123 05010000 20160209 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
20160210\05010000.123 05010000 20160210 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
20160210\05010000.124 05010000 20160210 10:10:10 06:06:06pm
```

I want to see all data of that Herd in the order of the index (descending Dir/DateTime) - newest first ie..  all the specific Herd in descending order

```
20160210\05010000.124 05010000 20160210 10:10:10 06:06:06pm
20160210\05010000.123 05010000 20160210 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
20160209\05010000.123 05010000 20160209 10:10:10 05:05:05pm
```

Code:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from HerdHist_tb where (hh_HerdNumber = @hh_HerdNumber)", myconnection);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hh_HerdNumber", v_herdNumber);
```

So how do I force the query to use the index `IX_herdHist_tb_Herd` so the data will display as I need?

Comment: This would really benefit from the tag [tag:sql]--very little of the actual question or provided answer deals with C#

Answer (score 2):

This is really a code smell, and it's generally a very bad practice to force a particular index to be used (for many reasons which you can Google), but the way you'd do it is:

```
select *
from HerdHist_tb
    WITH (INDEX(IX_herdHist_tb_Herd))
where (hh_HerdNumber = @hh_HerdNumber)
```

Also, there's no guarantee that the index isn't being used in the query. You might just want to order the results in your query:

```
select *
from HerdHist_tb
where (hh_HerdNumber = @hh_HerdNumber)
order by hh_HerdNumber ASC
```

Check your query / execution plans for more insight into whether the index is actually being used.

Comment: Why would you not simply add an `order by` clause though? The OP seems more concerned to me about getting ordered results than about how the ordering is forced.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - **forcing** a query to use an index is an indicating of a bad design, or bad programming - or both. You should never need to do this.

Also: forcing use of an index does **not** guarantee any order! If you need a specific order in your output, you **must** explicitly define an `ORDER BY` clause for your `SELECT` statement - there's no other way to do this.

And lastly: since your table has four columns, the index is on three of them, but your `SELECT` uses the `*` to request **all** columns from the table, most likely, the SQL Server query optimizer concludes that it's just more efficient to scan the table (since you need **all columns** anyway) instead of using the index - again: the fact SQL Server isn't using the index is indication that something is - at best - suboptimal in your setup.

Fix the **root cause** - don't tinker with the mere symptoms.....